# Sample n rows linearly spread in time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time-series

Let's say I have a table as follows:

```
datetime (datetime)  val (int)
2012-12-21 09:22:15    5
2012-12-20 18:20:15    4
2012-12-19 23:19:15    3
2012-12-18 13:45:15    8
2012-12-17 04:56:15    7
2012-12-16 01:50:15    2
2012-12-14 12:02:15    1
2012-12-13 12:02:15    4
2012-12-12 12:02:15    3
```

Given a number `n`, is it possible in MySQL to retrieve in one query, `n` rows equally spread out in time? So, rough examples:

`n=2`:

```
datetime (datetime)  val (int)
2012-12-21 09:22:15    5
2012-12-16 01:50:15    2
```

`n=3`:

```
datetime (datetime)  val (int)
2012-12-21 09:22:15    5
2012-12-18 13:45:15    8
2012-12-14 12:02:15    1
```

`n=4`:

```
datetime (datetime)  val (int)
2012-12-21 09:22:15    5
2012-12-19 23:19:15    3
2012-12-17 04:56:15    7
2012-12-14 12:02:15    1
```

As you can see, I want to get `n` records equally spread apart in time (if we'd like, we can also assume there's an `id autoincrement` that we can use instead of time). Looking around, I only found how to get every n rows - however, that use case is different.

Comment: is it to get m-th row, where m = floor(total-rows / n)

Comment: @ProGu correct (in that scenario `n` is the "time" or "id" interval)

Comment: when `n=4`, you example takes rows 1,3,5,7, where 9th row is in same distribution interval, but dropped. any rules? not why take 1,4,6,9 or 1,3,6,8? or they are all acceptable?